# Javascript — unable to set focus to a dynamically created textbox

Tags: javascript, focus

Problem:

I'm working on a JavaScript-based web application. The app has a feature where users can click on a row to update a detail view. The detail view contains an input box that should receive focus after the update, but the focus is not being set.

Question:

What can I do to set the focus on the input box after clicking the row? Are there any other methods that I haven't tried?

I've tried several solutions to set the focus on the input box, including:

1. Setting the input box to autofocus.
2. Using document.querySelector and element.focus().
3. Removing all other focusable elements from the page except for the input box.
4. Using setTimeout to wait for the page to load fully before setting focus.
5. Checking the state of the prompt control center before setting focus.
6. Adding tabindex=0 and display properties to the input box.

However, none of these solutions have worked. The input box appears to have focus in the logs, but it does not actually have focus on the page. Pressing the tab key sets the focus correctly, but this is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: If you are trying to set focus from inside a "click" handler, try placing the code that sets the focus in a brief timer callback. The "click" will set the focus to whatever you clicked on, but if you wait a few milliseconds you can set the focus successfully.

Comment: thanks! I did use setTimeOut like so without success:


`setTimeout(() => {
    const firstTextBox = document.getElementById('input-0');
    if (firstTextBox) {
      firstTextBox.focus();
    }
  }, 0);`

To clarify: according to the logs, the text box does have the focus, but it does not actually have the focus.

Comment: Well that's always worked for me, but your page layout may be different.

Comment: I stand corrected, it did work! I added it elsewhere in my code and it worked. If you answer my question, I will mark it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general problem with having a "click" event set focus to somewhere *other than the clicked-on element* is that the click itself will, as part of its normal behavior, alter the focus state. Even if you click on something like text (that is, not another input or button or whatever) the click will divert focus if you change it in the handler.

My rational mind suggests that preventing the default action on the "click" *should* work, but I've had mixed results. It could be that my negative experience was a very long time ago, so that is worth a try. My old standby method however is to perform the desired focus setting in something like a timeout handler. (A resolved Promise handler should work too.) So:

```
const target = document.getElementById("something");
something.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("desired-focus").focus();
    }, 1);
});
```

By doing it in a timeout handler, it happens only after the whole "click" process has finished. The delay won't be noticed by the user.